# Как исправить код микроразметки?

Tags: php, javascript, html, schema.org

Добрый день! Как исправить данный код, чтобы свойство itemprop="image" применялось только к первому элементу img в цикле, а к остальным не применялось?

```html
      <div class="goods-tab goods-gallery product-slider-holder clearfix">
        <div class="flexslider active product-gallery-holder">
          <ul class="slides">
            {% FOR goods_images %}
              <li class="item">
                <img src="{goods_images.LARGE}" alt="{goods_images.NAME}" data-zoom-image="{goods_images.LARGE}" itemprop="image" />
              </li>
            {% ENDFOR %}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Поставить счетчик и на 0 вешать.

Comment: Oma, в конкретном случае как это можно сделать?

Comment: у Вас с чем связан вопрос? с php или с js ? И где сам код Вашего "цикла"

Comment: ddeadlink,  c php,  код цикла начинается с  {% FOR goods_images %} и заканчивается {% ENDFOR %}, мне нужно сделать что то типа goods_images[0].LARGE или goods_images.first.LARGE, но в данном случае это не работает

Comment: шаблонизатор какой, фреймворк?